# Как посчитать сумму всех произведений K-V в Map используя stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

Исходный тип: `Map<Integer, Integer>`

Надо посчитать сумму используя стримы `sum = key1*value1 + ... + keyN*ValueN`

`map.entrySet().stream`.....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>() {{
            put(1, 1);
            put(2, 2);
            put(3, 3);
        }};

        var res = map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e -> e.getValue() * e.getKey())
                .reduce(0, Integer::sum);

        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```